# Speed up insert in Mariadb

Tags: php, database, validation, insert, mariadb

Please, if somebody can give me support.

My problem is:

I have a table with 8 fields and about 510 000 records. In a web form, the user select an Excel file and it's read it with SimpleXLSX. The file has about 340 000 lines. With PHP and SimpleXLSX library this file is loaded in memory, then with a for cicle the script read line by line, taken one data of ecah line and search this value in the table, if the data exists in the table, then does not insert the value, other wise, the values read it are stored in the table.

This process takes days to finish.

Can somebody suggest me some operation to speed up the process?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `and search this value in the table` ... where is the code which is doing this?

Comment: If the columns you check have a unique index, use `INSERT IGNORE` rather than a separate query to search for the value.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have many users, and they maybe use the web at the same time:

- you must change SimpleXLSX to js-xlsx, in webbrowser do all work but only write database in server

2. if you have few users (i think you in this case)

```
and search this value in the table
```

- this is cost the must time, if your single-to-single compare memory and database, then add/not-add to database.
- so you can read all database info in memory, (must use hash-list for compare),then compare all
  and add it to memory and mark newable
  at last 
  add memory info to database
- 
- because you database and xls have most same count, so...database become almost valueless
- just forget database, this is most fast in memory
- in memory use hash-list for compare

3. of course, you can let above run in database if you can use @Barmar's idea.. don't insert single, but batch

Answer (score 0):

Focus on speed on throwing the data into the database.  Do not try to do all the work during the `INSERT`.  *Then* use SQL queries to further clean up the data.

Use the minimal XLS to get the XML into the database.  Use some programming language if you need to massage the data a lot.  Neither XLS nor SQL is the right place for complex string manipulations.

If practical, use `LOAD DATA ... XML` to get the data loaded; it is very fast.

SQL is excellent for handling entire tables at once; it is terrible at handling one row at a time.  (Hence, my recommendation of putting the data into a staging table, not directly into the target table.)

If you want to discuss further, we need more details about the conversions involved.